# cors in spring boot app

Tags: javascript, java, spring, cors

I have a table called student with column name, password, domain.
I have a method in my controller that provides token to student for getting some resources.

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@RequestMapping(value = "/getToken")
public String provideToken() {
  return "tokenvalue"
}
```

In the database, there are multiple students and multiple student have different domain that calls the above method. E.g. 
**something.com/provideToken?username="user"&password="pass"**

In different domain there is a page that calls the above url. 
Now, How do i make sure that only those domain that are in the database can access above provideToken function.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
            SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        }

        @Bean
        public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {

            List<User> allUsers = userDao.findAll();
            List<String> originList = new ArrayList<>();
            for(User user: allUsers) {
                originList.add(user.getDomainName());
            }

            return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                    String[] origins = new String[originList.size()];
                    origins = originList.toArray(origins);
                    registry.addMapping("/getToken").allowedOrigins(origins);
                }
            };
        }
```

Comment: does `https://enable-cors.org/` have any information you can use?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**a `WebMvcConfigurer` for**](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurer.html) programmatic configuration of origins per mapping:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class MySpringBootApplication {

    @Autowired
    private MyDatabase myDatabase;

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                String[] origins = myDatabase.getAllowedOriginsForGetToken(); // example

                registry.addMapping("/getToken").allowedOrigins(origins);
            }
        };
    }

...
```

As you can see, it allows you to go to the database (or any other source) for getting the origins information.

Comment: Just some method of your code that would return an array of strings that would be the origins allowed for `/getToken`. It could go in the database or not, you make it what you need.